# Disable Windows 8 CharmsBar in WPF-Fullscreen App

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, charms-bar

I want to create a new fullscreen "kiosk" WPF Application for Windows 8.
It's not a modern UI app.

The app should be start automatically and must be unclosable.
A few things are already implemented. 
The app disables the hardware windows key with a registry value and
starts with Windows.

The only thing that doesn't work is the disabling of the Charms-Bar.
I've tested a lot of things, like a DisableCharmsHint-Registry Value.
But it doesn't work. And than I searched on the web and I've seen a API-Call, that should disable the CharmsBar - But it doesn't work.
I hope anybody could help.

Here is my helper-class. I call the EnableEdgeGestures - Method with the MainWindow-Handle and false - disable.

The result of the API-Call SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow is always 0.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Helpers {
    public class EdgeGestureUtil {
        #region Strukturen

        [StructLayout ( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4 )]
        public struct PropertyKey {
            public PropertyKey ( Guid guid, UInt32 pid ) {
                fmtid = guid;
                this.pid = pid;
            }

            [MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Struct )]
            public Guid fmtid;
            public uint pid;
        }

        [StructLayout ( LayoutKind.Explicit )]
        public struct PropVariant {
            [FieldOffset ( 0 )]
            public short vt;
            [FieldOffset ( 2 )]
            private short wReserved1;
            [FieldOffset ( 4 )]
            private short wReserved2;
            [FieldOffset ( 6 )]
            private short wReserved3;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private sbyte cVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private byte bVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private short iVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            public ushort uiVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private int lVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private uint ulVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private int intVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private uint uintVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private long hVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private long uhVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private float fltVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private double dblVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            public bool boolVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private int scode;
            //CY cyVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private DateTime date;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME filetime;
            //CLSID* puuid;
            //CLIPDATA* pclipdata;
            //BSTR bstrVal;
            //BSTRBLOB bstrblobVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private Blob blobVal;
            //LPSTR pszVal;
            [FieldOffset ( 8 )]
            private IntPtr pwszVal;
            //LPWSTR 
            //IUnknown* punkVal;
            //IDispatch* pdispVal;
            //        IStream* pStream;
            //        IStorage* pStorage;
            //        LPVERSIONEDSTREAM pVersionedStream;
            //        LPSAFEARRAY parray;
            //        CAC cac;
            //        CAUB caub;
            //        CAI cai;
            //        CAUI caui;
            //        CAL cal;
            //        CAUL caul;
            //        CAH cah;
            //        CAUH cauh;
            //        CAFLT caflt;
            //        CADBL cadbl;
            //        CABOOL cabool;
            //        CASCODE cascode;
            //        CACY cacy;
            //        CADATE cadate;
            //        CAFILETIME cafiletime;
            //        CACLSID cauuid;
            //        CACLIPDATA caclipdata;
            //        CABSTR cabstr;
            //        CABSTRBLOB cabstrblob;
            //        CALPSTR calpstr;
            //        CALPWSTR calpwstr;
            //        CAPROPVARIANT capropvar;
            //        CHAR* pcVal;
            //        UCHAR* pbVal;
            //        SHORT* piVal;
            //        USHORT* puiVal;
            //        LONG* plVal;
            //        ULONG* pulVal;
            //        INT* pintVal;
            //        UINT* puintVal;
            //        FLOAT* pfltVal;
            //        DOUBLE* pdblVal;
            //        VARIANT_BOOL* pboolVal;
            //        DECIMAL* pdecVal;
            //        SCODE* pscode;
            //        CY* pcyVal;
            //        DATE* pdate;
            //        BSTR* pbstrVal;
            //        IUnknown** ppunkVal;
            //        IDispatch** ppdispVal;
            //        LPSAFEARRAY* pparray;
            //        PROPVARIANT* pvarVal;
            //        

            /// <summary>
            /// Helper method to gets blob data
            /// </summary>
            private byte[] GetBlob ( ) {
                byte[] Result = new byte[ blobVal.Length ];
                Marshal.Copy ( blobVal.Data, Result, 0, Result.Length );
                return Result;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Property value
            /// </summary>
            public object Value {
                get {
                    VarEnum ve = ( VarEnum ) vt;
                    switch ( ve ) {
                        case VarEnum.VT_I1:
                            return bVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_I2:
                            return iVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_I4:
                            return lVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_I8:
                            return hVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_INT:
                            return iVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_UI4:
                            return ulVal;
                        case VarEnum.VT_LPWSTR:
                            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni ( pwszVal );
                        case VarEnum.VT_BLOB:
                            return GetBlob ( );
                    }
                    throw new NotImplementedException ( "PropVariant " + ve.ToString ( ) );
                }
            }
        }

        internal struct Blob {
            public int Length;

            public IntPtr Data;
            //Code Should Compile at warning level4 without any warnings, 
            //However this struct will give us Warning CS0649: Field [Fieldname] 
            //is never assigned to, and will always have its default value
            //You can disable CS0649 in the project options but that will disable
            //the warning for the whole project, it's a nice warning and we do want 
            //it in other places so we make a nice dummy function to keep the compiler
            //happy.
            private void FixCS0649 ( ) {
                Length = 0;
                Data = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region PropertyStore

        [ComImport, Guid ( "886D8EEB-8CF2-4446-8D02-CDBA1DBDCF99" ), InterfaceType ( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
        interface IPropertyStore {
            [MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
            void GetCount ( [Out] out uint cProps );

            [MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
            void GetAt ( [In] uint iProp, out PropertyKey pkey );

            [MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
            void GetValue ( [In] ref PropertyKey key, out PropVariant pv );

            [MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
            void SetValue ( [In] ref PropertyKey key, [In] ref PropVariant pv );

            [MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
            void Commit ( );
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methoden

        [DllImport ( "shell32.dll", SetLastError = true )]
        static extern int SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow ( 
            IntPtr handle, ref Guid riid, [Out, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] out IPropertyStore propertyStore );

        public static void EnableEdgeGestures ( IntPtr hwnd, bool enable ) {



            IPropertyStore pPropStore = null;
            int hr = 0;
            hr = SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow (
                hwnd, ref IID_PROPERTY_STORE, out pPropStore );

            if ( hr == 0 ) {
                PropertyKey propKey = new PropertyKey ( );
                propKey.fmtid = DISABLE_TOUCH_SCREEN;
                propKey.pid = 2;
                PropVariant var = new PropVariant ( );
                var.vt = VT_BOOL;
                var.boolVal = enable;
                pPropStore.SetValue ( ref propKey, ref var );
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject ( pPropStore );
            }
        }

        #endregion

        static Guid DISABLE_TOUCH_SCREEN    = new Guid ( "32CE38B2-2C9A-41B1-9BC5-B3784394AA44" );
        static Guid IID_PROPERTY_STORE      = new Guid ( "886d8eeb-8cf2-4446-8d02-cdba1dbdcf99" );
        static short VT_BOOL                = 11;
    }
}
```

Regards
Ronny

Answer (score 0):

Just kill `explorer.exe` when your application launches.